# PostgreSQL calculate weighted average based on user input

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with scores that lists for each film and critic, what score that critic gives to that film: **(film_id, critic_id, score)**. I have the following PostgreSQL query to find the 10 films that have the highest average score across a given array of critics:

```
SELECT 
    f_id, avg(f_score) 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            s.film_id as f_id, s.critic_id as c_id, s.score as f_score 
        FROM 
            score s
        WHERE 
            s.critic_id = ANY(ARRAY['CRITIC_BOB_0213', 'CRITIC_AMY_9671']) 
        GROUP BY 
            s.film_id, s.critic_id, s.score  
    ) 
sub 
GROUP BY 
    f_id 
ORDER BY 
    avg desc 
LIMIT 
    10;
```

In this case, the user would say that he wants to know the scores for critics Bob and Amy, and it returns:

```
f_id     | avg
"742545"   13.0330650266333
"220176"   6.7783259974
"662682"   6.52305498088333
...
```

Now, I want the user to be able to give a certain weight to a certain critic.
So basically, the user gives as input `[('CRITIC_BOB_0213', 0.923), ('CRITIC_AMY_9671', 0.212)]` (for instance if he values Bob's judgement more than Amy's), and I need the query to reflect that. So you would get a weighted average: `avg(score_bob*0.923 + score_amy*0.212)`. I need it to be in the query itself, the number of films is in the millions and I don't want to have to return them all before calculating the weighted average in my backend code.

Is this possible in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself by doing:

```
SELECT 
    f_id, avg(weighted_score)
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            s.film_id as f_id
        ,
        CASE
            WHEN s.critic_id='CRITIC_BOB_0213' THEN s.score*CRITIC_BOB_WEIGHT
            WHEN s.critic_id='CRITIC_AMY_9671' THEN s.score*CRITIC_AMY_WEIGHT
            ELSE -1
        END as weighted_score 
        FROM 
            score s
        WHERE 
            s.critic_id = ANY(ARRAY['CRITIC_BOB_0213', 'CRITIC_AMY_9671']) 
        GROUP BY 
            s.film_id, s.critic_id
    ) 
sub 
GROUP BY 
    f_id
ORDER BY 
    avg desc 
LIMIT 
    10;
```

Hope it will help others in the future.

Comment: `CRITIC_BOB_WEIGHT` is a field in the table or a variable?

Comment: It is the variable the user gives as input. In my backend code I just have a loop that constructs the query which loops over the user input and adds the `WHEN` lines when neccesary, using this variable.

Comment: The only issue I see is that this doesn't appear very scalable...  I would assume the user could feed any number of critics and weightings and you would want the query to be able to handle it?

Comment: Why would it not be scalable? Is the `CASE` expression not fast enough? Does it matter if it grows to, say, 100 `WHEN` lines? I am of course open to other solutions.

Comment: Yes, exactly...  it's not a matter of fast enough.  I have no doubt this will execute efficiently.  It's just the whole idea of building dynamic SQL always makes me ask if there might be a better way.  I don't mean to criticize the solution.  After all, it was your problem, and you are probably the best person to determine what solution best works.  Not only that, but at the moment I don't have a better suggestion.

Comment: I understand, and hoped that there would be a better way as well. I'm pretty new to (Postgre)SQL, but since I haven't got other answers yet, for now this seems like a good solution (works and is fast enough for my application at this moment).

Comment: Can you show an implementation of how this query is executed (ie how does it get those variables passed to it)?  I had an idea and could at least demonstrate the concept if I knew this.  Again, not to beat this horse to death, as you clearly have something that works for you, but in the interest of showing an alternative method I thought it might be helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97994/discussion-between-appel-and-hambone).